# Adding more data to an http request that made by form in html

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to send more data inside the body of an `<form>` ?

For example:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But I want to send the body:

```
{
  "fname":"<some name>",
  "lname":"<some last name>",
  "grant_type":"password"
}
```

I want to add the `grant_type` part as well, what's the best way to send this http request? In that case I must use ajax?

Comment: You can add an input type of hidden to the form.

Comment: Given the content of the form I feel it's also important to point out that users can see and modify hidden form fields and AJAX requests.  (And anything else you send from the client.)  You can certainly add values from the client to send to the server, just remember not to implicitly trust those values when they get to the server just because they were "hidden" on the client.

Comment: I thought about that, but it's a bit crooked way, not? @Teemu

Comment: I wouldn't say it's crooked, `hidden` is very commonly used practice. You can add the hidden element within a submit handler if you don't want users to see it in the code.

Comment: @spez: "crooked" how, exactly?  If the goal is to have an additional value in the form, why can't you include an additional value in the form?  What's the specific problem you're trying to solve and what is stopping you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `FormData` if you want to submit the form using Javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

```js
let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
let formData = new FormData(myForm);
formData.append("grant_type", "password");
```

Otherwise, use a hidden form field.

```html
<input name="grant_type" type="hidden" value="password">
```